# Conditional Probability question, depending on what colour ball is chosen, affects the 2nd event

Tags: conditional-probability

A box contains 5 black and 8 white balls. A ball is removed and replaced by two of the other color and then a second ball is drawn. Calculate:

(i) The probability that the second ball is white.

(ii) The probability that both balls drawn are the same colour.

Comment: There are 4 possible patterns with different probabilities: BB, WB, BW, WW.  What happens if you consider each of them?

Comment: I can work out each pattern, but for the 1st question, I have the formula for conditional probability, but I'm not sure how to calculate the 1st event?

Comment: So, to answer your hint, for BB, if Black is drawn, 2 whites are added, then another black is drawn, if W, then 2B added, then B is drawn...etc?

Comment: That was not quite my hint.  What is the probability that Black was drawn first and Black drawn second, i.e. BB? I would presume $\frac{5}{5+8} \times \frac{4}{4+10}$.  Can you do the same for the other three patterns? The probability that the second ball is white is the probability of BW plus the probability of WW.